# Does a von Neumann universe $V$ satisfy the $\omega$-global covering property for $V$ itself?

Tags: set-theory

$V$ is an inner model of itself.([ZF(C): Model or Inner Model](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2993674/zfc-model-or-inner-model/2993683#2993683))
Therefore the following theorem, Bukovský's theorem is satisfied:

Let N ⊆ M be an inner model.
 The following are
equivalent:
1. N satisfies the $κ$-global covering property for M.
2. There is a $κ$-c.c partial order P ∈ N and a generic G ⊆ P such that M =
N[G].
(ref. [this](http://www.math.harvard.edu/theses/senior/cavitt/cavitt.pdf))

In conclusion, V is an inner model of itself and there is ${\omega}$-c.c P and generic G such that V = V[G](trivial forcing extension) so V satisfies the ${\omega}$-global covering property for V itself.

Question:
It is it correct?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, but it's also *massive* overkill. $V$ trivially satisfies the $\kappa$-global covering property: just take $F(x)=\{f(x)\}$. There's no reason to invoke Bukovsky's theorem. (Indeed, *both* properties - that $V$ is an $\omega$-c.c. generic extension of itself, and that $V$ has the $\omega$-global covering property - are basically trivial.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.It seems that this question was exercise of Bukovský's theorem rather than new discovery.

Comment: @hinalogic I mean, Bukovsky's theorem is really irrelevant here since the properties in question are each trivial - using Bukovsky to get either one from the other is huge overkill.

Comment: @hina: I am confused as to the nature of the new discovery.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I’m sorry. I should have written not "exercise of Bukovsky's theorem rather than new discovery" but rather "not new discovery but rather exercise of Bukovsky's theorem".